# Odoo 9 Cannot inherit purchase.order

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I am trying to add a custom field to a **purchase.order** object in Odoo 9. I have done this to loads of other parts of the system without issue. However I keep getting.

> KeyError: Cannot find model purchase.order

Here is my code

```
class purchase_order(osv.Model):
    _inherit = "purchase.order"
    _columns = {
        'purchase_reference': fields.char("Purchase Reference")
    }

purchase_order()
```

I can't see what the issue is. I can even find almost exactly the same code as mine in the Odoo GitHub repo.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Check dependency of your custom module in __openerp__py. `purchase` must be there.

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. you're likely correct but should propose this as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

As from the shared code i have find that you are trying to inherit model  `purchase.order` [ `_inherit = "purchase.order"`] and want to know how to inherit it in the right way .

> In ODOO it's a basic necessity that whenever you want to **inherit** a
>   model that is create in some another module , you must associate  the
>   module name in the keyword `depends` of  `__openerp__.py`.

Below i am just posting the  `__openerp__.py` of a test module :

```
{
'name': 'My Module',
'version': '0.1',
'author': 'Prakash Sharma ',
'category': 'Sale',
'website': 'http://stackoverflow.com/users/5133838/prakash-sharma',
'description': """This is a test module .""",
'depends' : ['purchase'],
'demo': ['my_module.xml'],
'data': ['views/my_module.xml' ],
'auto_install': False,
'installable': True,
}
```

You  can try this [link](http://odoo-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/03_module_dev_01.html#manifest-file-openerp-py) also for the detail exploration of ODOO Manifest File `__openerp__.py`
This may help in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Emipro gave what I think is the correct answer.

I suggest you use the new API for your custome devs on Odoo 9, you'll find it much more convenient. Start here: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/howtos/backend.html

Answer (score 0):

make sure purchase module is installed, install it manually or add 'purchase' in your custom module's

```
    __openerp__.py
```

file as the value of 'depends'